# Is my aloe Vera dying

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, succulents, aloe

[[image: what are the marks on the leaves]]

[image]

The leaves have lots of indents, there are marks on the leaves and some of the leaf tips are turning brown

Answer (score 1):

So if the leaves started to thin, it could be due to:

1. It’s too dry. If the plant was left for long time without water, then just water it more often :)
2. It’s too wet and the roots were damaged. If the plant spent several days in very wet soil, then you should pick it from the soil and check that the roots are not rotten.

Aloes are very hardy, so it will definitely grow back even if all roots are lost, if replanted properly.

3. Sun damage. If the plant has been away from sun for a long time and then brought to direct sunlight, it could be damaged.